# What is the import statement for the firebase object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I wish to allow an anonymous user login to a Firebase Function.
Like so :

```js
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

*From : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth*

The thing is, I don't know what the `firebase` object is.

### What is the import statement I should use to get this `firebase` object ?

---

I've tried the following :

`const firebase = require('firebase-app');`

`const firebase = require('firebase');`

`const firebase = require('firebase-admin');`

Nothing seems to have the `auth().signInAnonymously()` property.

---

I get errors like `TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function` or `admin.auth(...).onAuthStateChanged is not a function` in the Function log.

---

This is the function I want to call : https://firebase.google.cn/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinanonymously

And this is the `firebase` object I want to import : https://firebase.google.cn/docs/reference/js/firebase

Comment: Or I get messages like `Error: Cannot find the firebase namespace; be sure to include firebase-app.js before this library.` when trying to do the firebase deploy

Comment: Can you show more code ? `auth` function should exist on `const firebase = require('firebase-admin');`

Comment: Where are you running this code? If you're using Node.js, please [edit] your question and add the appropriate tag `node.js`. If you're running in the browser, please indicate that by telling us what browser you're running when getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backend services, such as Cloud Functions, are not used for signing in users.  Sign-in always happens on the frontend, and the ID token for the user is managed there.  If you need to make the backend aware of the user for some HTTP request, you're supposed to pass the ID token from the client to the server, then [verify the ID token with the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Cloud Functions server instances are transient and will not hold correctly and persistently hold the sign-in tokens, which is why you need to pass them from the client on each request.

I suggest reviewing the Firebase Authentication documentation for the frontend platforms you're working with in order to start getting sign-in implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

@doug You are correct that backend functions are not meant to be used for signing in users BUT you can if you wanted.

I often wire up a front end and a backend.

The backend has functions with the embedded Auth API code.

Then deploy as Cloud Functions in Firebase Functions.

Then it's just a case of passing through some data from frontend (using fetch, REST) to each endpoint.

Then from there on respond and set a flag or two.

yes yes you may not get the front end tokens from Firebase however you can create
so not quite the same but similar.

This is full stack though but if it's purely front end then one can always use the sign up/in popup apis.

Hope that helps.